# Inserting a string in the middle of page's permalink?

Tags: permalinks, filters

I know the more sensible approach for this would be to rely on archives so that my URL for news would be:

domain.com/news/

However, due to how I am setting this up for the client to easily modify the content, I have created 3 news pages (each referencing 3 categories), inside each one, there is code to display the news listing for each category.

I would like to change the permalink for those pages so that instead of being:

domain.com/in-the-media

The permalink is:

domain.com/news/in-the-media

I have looked around and the hook `page_link` seems to be what I would like.

Here is my callback function (which I have verified gets called):

```
    public static function change_news_permalinks( $url, $post ) {  
        $url = "{$url}something/";
        return $url;
    }
```

This is just a test, if this worked, then I would continue and write the conditions so that the change would only take place when it's one of those 3 pages.

However, regardless of what page I view, the permalink remains unchanged when the page loads.

Am I using this incorrectly or am I misinterpreting what this hook actually allows you to carry out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`page_link` is not going to work as even though you change what it shows or uses, that's not going to be detected when the URL is accessed -- which requires handling to parse it during the request.

You could look at adding rewrites, or what is probably easier you could use try using something like this (or view their code to see how they do it):
https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/

Here's how they are doing it:
https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/custom-permalinks/trunk/frontend/class-custom-permalinks-frontend.php

Comment: Thanks for that, I was looking at the code and it's not simple stuff, it all happens inside ``parse_request`` and it's not just copy/paste change-change xD Will put this on the back-burner and think of Plan B instead, appreciate the response.